# Unique File Renaming Issue

Tags: c#, regex, file-rename, file-manipulation

I am developing an app right now that reads in data from a windows from and generates an XML file based on the input.

I am tasked with creating a new file each time the form is updated (User presses "Submit").  (so far so good)

Here is the catch: The file has to be named after a prominent field input. (If the user types '993388CX' in the text box, the app would rename the pending file 993388CX.xml).

I understand how to actually rename a file in C#, but not how to rename it based on a form's input. Do any classes/methods exist that will dynamically rename the file based on the form input?

**Code:**

**//Reads info1 from user input on the app UI and generates XML statement**

```
        XTemp = XDoc.CreateElement("New_Info");
        XTemp.InnerText = info1.Text;
        Xsource.AppendChild(XTemp);

          XDoc.Save(@"C:\oldfile.xml");
```

**I need the new file to be renamed after the string in info1.Text**

If the user input was "John5", the file needs renamed to john5.xml

Thank you

Comment: Consider adding validation to the form to require the .xml file extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either directly save it with the correct name:

```
XDoc.Save(String.Format("C:\\{0}.xml",info1.Text));
```

**OR**

Rename it afterwards

```
File.Move("c:\\oldfile.xml", String.Format("C:\\{0}.xml",info1.Text));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    XDoc.Save(@"C:\" + info1.Text + ".xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

`File.Move` should do what you want.